# How to merge multiple xlsx files into one single xlsx file with Different sheets

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have multiple xlsx files

```
sales-feb-2014.xlsx
sales-jan-2014.xlsx
sales-mar-2014.xlsx
```

I have merged all 3 sheets into one data set using file name as INDEX[0]

script :

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import glob
    import os


    all_data = pd.DataFrame()
    for f in glob.glob(r'H:\Learning\files\sales*.xlsx'):
       df = pd.read_excel(f)
       df['filename'] = os.path.basename(f)
       df = df.reset_index().set_index('filename')
print(df)
```

Now Data looks like this :

```
   file name            col1   col2 col3 
    sales-jan-2014.xlsx  ....   .... ...

    sales-feb-2014.xlsx  ....   .... ...

    sales-mar-2014.xlsx  ....   .... ...
```

here I want to load new xlsx file where I need to load

```
sales-jan-2014.xlsx into sheet1 
sales-feb-2014.xlsx into sheet2  
sales-mar-2014.xlsx into sheet3
```

I have tried with this script :

```
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
for filename in df.index.get_level_values(0).unique():
    temp_df = df.xs(filename, level=0)
    temp_df.to_excel(writer,filename)
writer.save()
```

after executing this script i'm getting error :

**loc, new_ax = labels.get_loc_level(key, level=level,
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'get_loc_level'**

can you please suggest where I'm missing

Comment: Maybe you want to use the xlsxwriter library

Comment: above imports are supporting xlsxwriter @Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below code :

```
import os
import pandas as pd
dirpath = "C:\\Users\\Path\\TO\\Your XLS folder\\data\\"
fileNames = os.listdir(dirpath)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(dirpath+'combined.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for fname in fileNames:
    df = pd.read_excel(dirpath+fname)
    print(df)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=fname)    
writer.save()
```

You can also use your code by make below changes :

```
    for f in glob.glob(r'H:\Learning\files\sales*.xlsx'):
       df = pd.read_excel(f)
       df['filename'] = os.path.basename(f)
       df = df.reset_index()
       print(df.columns)
       df.set_index(['filename','index'], inplace=True)
```

and saving it as you have done.

I hope this helps

Comment: fileNames = os.listdir(dirpath)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'H:\\Learning\x0ciles\\sales*.xlsx'

Comment: dirpath should not be the path of the file, but the path of folder that contain your multiple *.xlsx files                                                                                                          That folder should only contain excel files.

Comment: can you please implement in my code and post it @shishir

Comment: You are getting above error because of **xs method of pandas** as that function only works, **when you have multi-level index dataframe**. So convert you data frame to multi level index and then it will work.   [Read here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)

Comment: sure let me implement in my code and get back to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195619/discussion-between-shishir-naresh-and-mohan111).

Comment: I have modified my code according to your answer but it is generating excel file for only Jan 2014.xlsx

Comment: Your question was why you were getting that error, i think i have answered your question correctly and given you a solution too. So if you need anything else please raise another question and upvote my this answer.

Comment: i have found another answer and it is giving me exact result ..coming to your solution it is creating filename and appending index column but not looping multiple sheets ..but you have spent time on my question..thanks for that ..tick from my side